# Angular 2 , create dictionary using typescript <key, value> and load json file to put data in it

Tags: json, dictionary, angular

I need some help creating a dictionary or list which has the  structure. I have created a json file (placed it in my angular 2 project), where I need to load this data to the dictionary created.

My Json file looks like (sample):

```
{
 "ACCOUNT_LOGIN_TEXT": "Login",
 "ACCOUNT_LOGOUT_TEXT": "Logout",
 "BOOKING_ACTIVE_HEADER_TEXT": "ACTIVE BOOKINGS",
 "BOOKING_LOADING_TEXT": "Loading bookings",
 "BOOKING_NONACTIVE_HEADER_TEXT": "NON ACTIVE BOOKINGS",    
}
```

*Its placed in a folder called Locales and the file name is localeEN.json*

The ACCOUNT_LOGIN_TEXT should be the key, and value should be the text. Is there an easy way of loading a json file and iterate over it to put the values down in a dictionary, so you can use it further?

Have created an AppService, because I need to load this before the rest of the components.

```
@Injectable()
export class AppService {

    localeResource: 

    constructor() {

    }

    getLocaleResources(locale: string) {

    }

}

interface Locale {
    key: string,
    value: string
}
```

Not sure how the localeResource type should be? Have created a interface, but I'm not sure if its good to use that as a type.

Hope someone can advice me.

**Update**

I managed to create an pipe which actually work :)

```
export class ResourcePipe implements PipeTransform {

value: string = "";

constructor(private appService: AppService) {

}

transform(key: string) {

    this.appService.getResourceValue(key).subscribe((data: any) => {

        if (typeof data === "string") {
            this.value = data;
        }

    })

    return this.value;
}
}
```

The pipe gets the value from the service.
Then i can use pipes in angular2, like:

```
{{ SOME_TEXT | resource }} and it works quite good.
```

Comment: check out http://www.typescriptlang.org/Handbook#interfaces-array-types

interface Locale {
    [index: string]: string;
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could load your resource into the constructor and set the result into your localResource variable. You could also leverage an EventEmitter to notify service users (components) that the i18n data are loaded.

Here is a sample implementation:

```
@Injectable()
export class AppService {
  localeResource: any;
  localResourceLoadedEvent: EventEmitter<boolean> = new EventEmitter();
  localResourceLoaded: boolean;

  constructor(private http:Http) {
    return this.http.get(`Locales/localeEn.json`)
             .map(res => res.json())
             .subscribe((data) => {
               this.localeResource.En = data;
               this.localResourceLoaded = true;
               this.localResourceLoadedEvent.emit(true);
             });
  }

  getLocaleResources(locale: string) {
    return localeResource[locale];
  }
}
```

Note that this service needs to be shared by all the application and should be defined when calling the bootstrap function:

```
bootstrap(AppComponent, [ AppService ]);
```

In your component, you could have this:

```
@Component({
  template: `
    <div *ngIf="resourceLoaded">
      (...)
    </div>
  `
})
export class MyComponent {
  constructor(private appService:AppService) {
    this.resourceLoaded = appService.localResourceLoaded;
    if (!this.resourceLoaded) {
      this.appService.localResourceLoadedEvent.subscribe((resourceLoaded) => {
        this.resourceLoaded = resourceLoaded;
        this.resource = this.appService.getLocaleResources('En');           
      });
    } else {
      this.resource = this.appService.getLocaleResources('En');           
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I'm thinking of having a pipe loading the resources from this AppService. Do I still have to bootstrap the service then or?

I mean by that, the other Components are using the pipe to get the right resource :)

Comment: Yes you need to provide the service when bootstrapping the application to share the same instance of the service... Perhaps I'm wrong, but it doesn't seem that you need a pipe.

Comment: Feel free to add a concrete sample where you want to use a pipe so I could discuss this ;-)

Comment: Give me some time ;) I'm still at work, so later I will post and example of how I'm trying to implement that pipe.

Comment: Sorry it took a little while. I managed to create the service, and a pipe which ask the service for a value.